# How to populate HTML table with results and filter through them

Tags: php, html, select, filter, html-table

This is my code so far. Im attempting to display one table of my database in a table through html. I then want to be able to filter through these resutls using a keyword, however, the results arent even displaying at this point, im unsure as to why? All the code is currently in one file, calendar.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

}else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM knockout"; //selecting all results in table and filtering
  $search = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query){
  include_once "action/dbcon.php";
  $filter = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  return $filter;
}
?>

    <form>
    <input type=text name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Search">
    <input type=submit name="search" value="filter">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Id:</th>
        <th>Team 1:</th>
        <th>Team 2:</th>
        <th>Date::</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search)); ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['knockout_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['knockout_team1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['knockout_team2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['knockout_date']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
  </form>
```

Comment: i think u forgot to add method here `<form>` and u are not using `valueToSearch` this anywhere and dont know why are u using session here. in last on page load, you will get undefined variable just becuase of this `mysqli_fetch_array($search)`

Comment: "the results arent even displaying at this point"  The filtered results or the unfiltered results?

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search));` remove the `;`? :)

Comment: fixed while statement and added a method to my form. Still not results, the ValueToSearch will be added later im just trying to see why there are no results at the minute

Comment: @Sam.92 Not remove, but replace with the correct `:`

Comment: Question of the nature: please help me debug my code will be closed in general, try to debug your code yourself and then come back and ask a specific question, please read [ask]

Comment: what does `:` do? Forgive my ignorance, i'm new to PHP myself and have literally the same code as above in my project, without the `:` still works too :) @PatrickQ

Comment: oh wow, silly me, the results are now showing. Just one small problem, They arent contained within the table, theyre just sort of running away. HTML issue i guess. Dont suppose anyone sees anything wrong with the table elements?

Comment: @Sam.92 This isn't the proper forum to explain it, but review [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).  Most control structures can be expressed multiple ways.

Comment: @breadley You are closing your table after the first (header) row

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: move the </table> tag lower :)

Comment: well thanks for the help everyone, glad someone else found this useful as well